# Strange (unfamilar screen) on my Galaxy Tab?

Tags: factory-reset, bootloader, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1.  It was powered off and charging when my nephew picked it up and turned in on.  When he handed it to me on the screen was a graphic of an open box, the android logo with the words downloading.

It has been in this state for 4 hours now and I cannot switch the device on or off.  Please help me understand what has happened and what I should do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your device is in Download Mode. I don't have that device, but if the battery doesn't come out, you will probably need to use ADB and send an `adb reboot` to get it out of Download mode. If you don't know how to use ADB, then you can just let the battery die. I don't like that option though because the same image will be on the screen for an extended period of time.

Does the screen look like this:
[image]

To use ADB:

- Download the USB Drivers from [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/GT-P7510MAYXAB)
- Download the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- connect the device to your computer via USB cable
- open a command prompt where the Android SDK was installed and change to the platform-tools directory. for example, my sdk is installed at c:\android-sdk so I run the following:

  C:\android-sdk> cd platform-tools

then try to reboot with adb:

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\> adb reboot
```

if that doesn't work try the following command:

```
C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\> fastboot reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, what is an adb reboot and do I execute?

Comment: yes, Thats the screen.

Comment: see my updates, hopefully it helps

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but this wont help.  My computer OS is Ubuntu 12.04 (linux) and the drivers you are suggesting are for WIndows. I didnt include this information in my question stem as I didnt think it was relevant ( and its clearly stated on my profile)

Comment: Make sure you have the linux sdk tools installed, and then, with the USB cable from your PC to your tablet plugged in, do this from your terminal, `sudo fastboot reboot`

Comment: download mode is different from adb. That most probably won't help, or am I missing sth. here? I'd say, as in my answer below: Let it drain or issue an innocent command via odin or [heimdall (linux)](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads). LIke 'heimdall detect' or 'heimdall download-pit'

Comment: Also note for the recovery: Issuing 'adb reboot' will reboot again to the recovery (at least from my experience with my Desire/Nexus S)

Comment: if you use ubuntu, its even easier, just get the android sdk for ubuntu and run "fastboot reboot". you dont need drivers.

Comment: @RyanConrad: Don't Samsung devices have 4 modes of operation: "download mode" (use with odin/heimdall), "fastboot mode", "recovery mode" and "normal mode"? Which mode is this device in, when it shows 'downloading..."? I'd guess, the first? Question to the OP: which of the following commands shows something:  "heimdall detect", "fastboot devices" or "adb devices" (run all as root)?

Comment: @ce4 i dont know if samsung devices have a true "fastboot" mode, but adb or fastboot can detect the device when in download mode, so it should be able to send the reboot command to it.

Comment: Just to be clear I am accepting this answer (however I just let the battery die and turned the device one again.  I will look to install the linux sdk tools and prepare both my device and PC for future occurrences should they happen.  Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 3):

You most probably see this, right:

[image]

This is the Galaxy Tab's 'download mode' to install new firmware as a last resort via Samsung's Odin or to side-load aftermarket firmware.

You can wait for the battery to drain by itself without taking further action.

Comment: Nice to know it helped you. The easiest way  for a regular consumer but it needs some time though (until the battery ins empty)

Answer (score -1):

I don't own a galaxy tab but some tablets have a hard reset button similar to windows power reset button. It's generally a small hole  and you can use a pin to reboot the device by pressing  the pin in the hole for few seconds. Basically what it does is it reboots the tablet. You don't require to wait for the battery drain.